# Gnome shell uses excessive amounts of CPU?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, cpu, cpu-load, intel-cpu

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04LTS, with only the Built-in extensions (i.e. Desktop Icons, AppIndicators and Dock) installed. Since updating to 22.04 I noticed that my mouse would begin to stutter frequently, and upon investigating via `top` I found out that the gnome shell frequently uses upwards of 80-90% of CPU, with spikes occurring when the mouse is moved erratically.

I am using Wayland and would like to keep it that way for the App-isolation.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Edit: Dell XPS-13 with Intel i7 Core, no dedicated GPU, 16 GB RAM. It's a dist-upgrade, not a fresh install.

Comment: Please tell us details about your computer: brand name and model of the computer, graphics chip/card and amount of RAM. It will give us a chance to suggest alternatives to standard Ubuntu with Gnome. The Ubuntu community flavours Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu have lighter desktop environments and in some cases also lighter standard application programs. By the way, is your current system dist-upgraded from a previous version or is it a fresh installation of 22.04.x LTS?

Comment: Added the info!

Comment: That computer should work well with standard Ubuntu and Gnome. There might be some problem due to upgrading (some cruft left from the previous version). You could test 22.04.x LTS live (booted from a USB pendrive) and maybe consider a fresh installation if the live system works better than your current dist-upgraded system.

Comment: Yeah, I was really hoping to get around a fresh installation. But testing a live version of Ubuntu  for the same issues is a great idea, thanks!